# Is there possible to use SQL Lag function itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, cumulative-sum

I need to find solution for my SQL report issue.
My issue is related to find appropriate way about using `lag` function for the column that was came from `lag` function.

Here it is picture to clarify my problem

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your question, but why not use a CTE ?. Put the first LAG inside a CTE, and then you can query it again using a second LAG.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: as above said, I often use CTE/subquery with LAG too. 1st one to calculate Difference from last row or actual last row value (by whatever logic), then do a filter on it, or in your case, you can add the diff like Column1+Diff

Comment: @MarcGuillot can you give more practical example of using first and second LAG?

Comment: @JerryHung Yes, but it will always get the current from 1st difference, not the previuos calculation of 2nd. :/

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a simple running total. You don't need `lag()` for that. When using an aggregate like `sum()` together with an `order by` in the window definition, it will give you just that.

But you you **have to** specify an `order by`, because rows in a table don't have any implied ordering.

```
select column1, 
       sum(column1) over (order by ???) as column1_calculation
from the_table
order by ???
```

You need to replace the `???` in the above statement with the column that defines the sort order of your rows. Very often a date/time column is used for that to get the running total over time.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5604e71a2d7b463696f93f64a39db305)

Comment: Yes, I have the date as column, but if do replace ??? with my date column, it will just do group by date for column1_calculation.

Comment: Then your date column has the same value for all rows and isn't suitable for an `order by`, it works as expected if the sort column has distinct values: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=20fa4dd253ea238436005df24d83abef

Comment: This is ok for me, but i need to include date column in the select statement. If I include it by your example, it won't return me correct values.

Comment: @mp94: then there is something you are not telling us, because including the date column will certainly not change anything: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5604e71a2d7b463696f93f64a39db305

Comment: are you trying to partition by date? because I am totally agreed with @a_horse_with_no_name as including date column won't affect your result